# Create custom progress bar component like opportunity in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

Create custom progress bar component like opportunity in lightning on any custom object and create any pick list which are should be created on into them

Comment: what is it exactly that you are asking? I invite you to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. If you are trying to get help with creating the component, please provide us what you have attempted so far, otherwise, this question is most likely to be closed, thanks!

Comment: In W18, a new Component/widget is being released that has this functionality. Check the release notes. You'll only need to wait a few weeks for it.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yes, but there's already a Standard Component if the user just wants to add a Path to a Record Page.

Answer (score 3):

If you really can't wait until the Winter '18 release, there's already an open-sourced version that allows you to do just this, located on GitHub, called [AnythingPath](https://github.com/mshanemc/AnythingPath) (*disclaimer: I have no involvement with this project*). You can deploy it to your org with just a few clicks using the Deploy to Salesforce button located on the page. This allows you to bind to any standard or custom field on any standard or custom object. Error checking is sparse, but as long as you use it correctly, it should work reasonably well.

If you're interested in just adding a Path to a record Layout, you can do so by going to Setup > Customize > Path > Path Settings, enabling the settings, building a Path for your object, then creating a Record Page for your object in the Lightning App Builder. You'll need to place whatever components you'd like to have on your record page's layout.